# Django, how can I loop through the choices in HTML and display in radio buttons?

Tags: html, django

In Django I have defined some Questions and I want to give a form to users to create own Choices. The output I'm getting in HTML is drop down box but I want to have it in 'radio button' format.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in context %}
    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.questionText }}" value="">
    {{ question }}
    <label for=""></label>
    {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Models.py:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choiceText = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choiceText
```

Views.py:

```
def addchoice(request):
    form_class = AddChoiceForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = form.save()
    else:
        context = form_class()

    return render(request, 'polls/add_a_choice.html', {'context': context})
```

The output I am getting is attached is added as image. [Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BUH8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't paste the `AddChoiceForm` code but I can imagine how it looks like.

The thing is that you are iterating through the form (it's form fields) and generating the `radio` inputs on your own and in the next line you are rendering the default html of the `question` form field which in this case is a `select`.

You can do two thing from here:

1. Drop the `{{ question }}` and render the field completely by your own - you will have access to the fields attributes (like choices) in the template.
2. Change the form widget in your form class. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/ and then drop the idea of rendering the `radio` on your own.

If I may - I'd suggest you to follow a style guide - I see you are mixing up a little and you can find your code messy in a while. For e.g `questionText` should be `question_text`. And when you `render` the whole dict you are passing is the `context` so naming the form by `context` is not a great idea (for example took me a while to decipher what you are doing there).